# Swift3 video file upload along with one more form parameter(can be skipped from form and sent as url path)

Tags: ios, alamofire, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask, urlsessiontask

I have searched for a long time but didn't find any good resource on how to do this. 
The api expects one form parameter "user_id"**(for now sending its as urlpath not form parameter)** and other "file" for the video file. please provide some code sample either using URLSession Task or any library for iOS.

Tried Alamofire:

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(self.fileurl, withName: "file")
    }, to:"http://www.www.www/upload/8590",
       headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(SharedPreferences.preferences.getKeyValue(key: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_key))"] )
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _ , _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                print("uploding>>>>>>")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print("done")

            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("failed")
            print(encodingError)

        }
```

This throws 500 from server saying it can't read Header first byte using UTF-8 encoding.

```
    message = "An Error OccuredInvalid header string: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 1: invalid start byte";
result = "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/www/wb_ios/wb_app/views.py\", line 94, in post\n    user_auth = jwt_decode_handler(auth).get('sub')\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py\", line 104, in jwt_decode_handler\n    unverified_payload = jwt.decode(token, None, False)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py\", line 70, in decode\n    payload, signing_input, header, signature = self._load(jwt)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jwt/api_jws.py\", line 177, in _load\n    raise DecodeError('Invalid header string: %s' % e)\nDecodeError: Invalid header string: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 1: invalid start byte\n";
status = 500;
```

}

Additionally, I can use postman to send the video successfully. Using form-data field like shown in images.
[body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLpmB.png)
[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHsJE.png)

finally I also tried :

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.www.www/upload/8590")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let boundary = "------------------------your_boundary"

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("ios", forHTTPHeaderField: "client")
    request.setValue(Constants.AUTH_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.AUTH_KEY_key)
    request.setValue("Bearer " + SharedPreferences.preferences.getKeyValue(key: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_key)!, forHTTPHeaderField: Constants.AUTH_AUTHORIZATION_key)
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    var movieData: NSData?
    do {
        movieData = try NSData(contentsOfFile: fileurl.path, options: NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
        print(movieData)
    } catch _ {
        movieData = nil
        return
    }

    let body = NSMutableData()

    // change file name whatever you want
    let filename = "upload.mov"
    let mimetype = "video/mov"

    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(movieData! as Data)
    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as! NSData, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(dataString)
    }

    task.resume()
```

this also throws error like this:

```
{"status":500,"message":"An Error Occuredu'file'","result":"Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/www/wb_ios/wb_app/views.py\", line 104, in post\n    file_obj = request.data['file']\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py\", line 85, in __getitem__\n    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))\nMultiValueDictKeyError: \"u'file'\"\n"})
```

Comment: In the second example(URLSession) server doesn't expect filename in form data, but i don't think I makes any difference.
If it couldn't upload the form properly the server can't read the dictionary properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift3.0**

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
            for (key, value) in parameter {
                MultipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
            }

// here you can upload only mp4 video
                multipartFormData.append(self.fileurl!, withName: "file", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
// here you can upload any type of video            
                 multipartFormData.append((self.fileurl.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false))!, withName: "File")

            print(MultipartFormData)
        },to:"http://www.www.www/upload/8590",headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(SharedPreferences.preferences.getKeyValue(key: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_key))"]
            )
        { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result.value ?? String())
                    print(response.data ?? NSData())
                    // send to completion block
                    completion(response.data as AnyObject? ?? NSData())
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                errorOccured(encodingError as NSError?)

            }
        }
```

Comment: in line                  multipartFormData.append(("VIDEO".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false))!, withName: "Type")
 what is "VIDEO"?

Comment: Add ur url inplace of  video , you  just use this
                multipartFormData.append(self.fileurl!, withName: "file", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")  and comment  that line.Please let me know whether it works or not.

Comment: I am fed up with the build failures once i built the app for ipad. Didn't expect iOS to be more troublesome than android. Will post the results asap.

Comment: It worked with this line.

multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(self.fileurl, withName: "file")
        }

I don't know why it didn't work with extra parameters like mimetype.
Additionally if you get time can you direct me in direction where I would have to upload a bigger file, and best practices for that(like background upload) using alamofire. Thanks you. I will post complete solution when everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Can we do it with URLSession ?

Comment: @ Awais Fayyaz : sorry for late reply, yes we can do by using URLSession.